# NHibernate autoincrement string column

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, auto-increment

I want to have a column of type string that will be composed of static prefix and dynamic auto incremented integer. Number should autoincrement on every insert. This column is not PK but it should act like id. Also i would like to filter on that column.
Something like

- PREFIX_0000
- PREFIX_0001
- PREFIX_0002
- PREFIX_0003

I don't want to store a counter in some table.
Is there a possibility to do that on NHibernate mapping level? Or any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you still have a autonumber or assigned int for your PK? Also can the word PREFIX_ change or is it same throughout?

Answer (score 0):

in you DTO you can make a getter which returns a prefix_######ID:

```
public string MyAutoIncrement 
{
    get { return string.Format("{0}_{1:D8}",this.Prefix,this.Id); }
}
```

Comment: That was my first intent but what about insertion and autoincrementation?